# Modify background: webkit-gradient with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, gradient

This should be fairly simple. All I need to do is pass a new block of parameters to my body css tag webkit gradient with a javascript function that gets called from a link. Here's what I tried (among 200 other things):

CSS

```
body
{
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font-size:100%;
    color:#444;
    position:relative;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #154d9e, #b8d8e4);
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function changeBack()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.background="-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000)";
    document.body.style.background="-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000)";
}
</script>
```

Neither of those two lines work. What gives?

Comment: [This example](http://www.larsko.org/v/beta/imageblend/) may help -- click on "Position" and you can change the gradient with the slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because *document.getElementsByTagName("body")* returns an array of elements. You need to specify which element it is. There is only one body tag on a page so this should work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background="-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000)";
```

Comment: This is a webkit browser only solution!  It will fail cross-browser testing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I success with use linear-Gradient unless -webkit. You can replace rgb colors by Hexadecimal format (ex. #F767676).

```
 document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(0, 0, 255))";
```

Here is a working fiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/cdgpts9n/